# Query comparing strings works in Oracle, but not in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working with a very simple query:

```
SELECT id FROM infotable WHERE email = 'joe.blow@smiths.com'
```

This query returns a result in Oracle 10g, going through the Golden32 front end.

When I try the same query going through Java/the JDBC I get nothing.

I tried both PreparedStatement and Statement, no joy.   I tried putting `'joe.blow@smiths.com'` and email in various combinations of upper() and lower()  alone as well together.   I also selected on all of the email values from infotable, putting string markers next to the output to eliminate whitespace in the database as an issue ( I also wrapped the email field in rtrim() and ltrim() ).

Any ideas of what it might be?

Comment: Show us the JDBC code. Also does `SELECT id FROM infotable` return anything?

Comment: Example code would help. Are you sure you are connecting as the same user on the Java side that you are via the Golden query tool?

Comment: Tomasz Nurkiewicz, I didn't include the JDBC because it was so boiler plate basic.

Comment: GriffeyDog, it turned out that there were two different passwords, both of which would work, but not equally.  I have the right password now and I am getting my results through the JDBC.  If you want to post your comment as an answer I will give you the green check mark for it.

Comment: Done. Glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are connecting as the same user on the Java side that you are via the Golden query tool?